# NgModel update on both onBlur & onSubmit

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-forms

I am trying to create a form with inputs that only update onBlur (`[ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"`). But a side effect of this is that the form is no longer submitted once the user hits 'enter', since the model is only updated onBlur. (same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48636334/update-form-values-both-on-blur-and-submit-in-angular) question, but it has no answer)

As a result of this the form is marked invalid, since there is a value in the input field, but the model is not yet updated with the value.

Versions:
- Angular `6.0.7`
- @angular/forms `6.0.7`

---

**HTML example**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="login()" #loginForm="ngForm" [ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}" [validate-on-submit]="loginForm">
  <input type="text" ([NgModel])="user.username"/>
  <input type="password" ([NgModel])="user.password"/>
</form>
```

When entered a valid text in both fields and hitting 'enter', the form validates and marks password (the input that had the focus) as invalid, since the NgModel has not yet been updated, and thus the value is invalid.

---

**What do I want**

So what I am looking for is a way to validate on both `onBlur` aswell as `onSubmit`. I know that since Angular 5 we have the option `[ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"`, but is there a way to give 2 parameters to this object?

(`[ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: ['blur', 'submit']}"` doesn't seem to work)

Almost forgot, I do **not** want the model updated `onChange` (creates annoying messages that are not very helpfull, since the user is still typing..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a third, invisible input in your form, and give it a template variable. Before submitting, simply focus this input, which will trigger the `onBlur` update :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="focuser.focus(); login()" #loginForm="ngForm" [ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
  <input type="text" ([NgModel])="user.username"/>
  <input type="password" ([NgModel])="user.password"/>
  <input type="hidden" #focuser>
</form>
```

Note that this is one of the many workarounds you can use, *not an actual solution*

Comment: Doesn't this just update the value for the hidden input instead of the complete form?

Comment: @Pilatus no, the update on blur is defined at the form level (and subsequentely on every input). This means that when the user leaves an input, the value of that input is updated. If you input an username, then you hit `Tab`, the value is updated and you go on password. If you then enter your password and hit enter, you won't leave the input, and not update the value. If you decide to focus *anything else*, you will leave the input, and thus update the value.

Comment: This is not completely true. When I programatically change the focus (I get the hidden input via @ViewChild and then call this.input.nativeElement.focus()), it won't update the model, but the input does lose focus.

Comment: @Mr.wiseguy then you should try [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Events/blur) on your input elements (not the hidden one)

Comment: @trichetriche, I've tried calling 'blur()' on the input field, but the problem is that the form is already validated when it is submitted, so changing the value afterwords won't work (the model update takes to long to have effect on the validation)

Comment: That does work, but then I need to give the form to my component and set a timeout arround the `form.valid`. I have a directive that listens to the submit event, do you know if there is a way to patch it here so that I won't have to monkey patch each form in my application?

Comment: If I were faced with this issue, I would try to make a form component with some `ng-content`, and apply what you've just did (timeout, blur inputs, etc).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174773/discussion-between-mr-wiseguy-and-trichetriche).

Answer (score 1):

**The solution - A form component**

After following the advice of @trichetriche (creating a separate component that holds the logic of the form) and letting template driven forms go in favor of reactive forms I found the following solution:

```
@Component({
  selector: "val-message-form",
  templateUrl: "./message-form.html"
})
export class MessageFormComponent {

  /**
   * The form group that holds all the input fields and the logic of the input fields
   * @type {FormGroup}
   */
  @Input()
  public formGroup: FormGroup;

  /**
   * The function that will be called when the form is valid
   * The template that includes this component can listen to this event for the submit action
   * @type {EventEmitter}
   */
  @Output()
  private onSubmit = new EventEmitter();

  /**
   * Notify all listeners that the form has been submitted
   * NOTE: Notify will only work if the form is valid
   */
  public submitForm(): void {
    if (this.formGroup.valid) {
      this.onSubmit.emit();
    } else {
      this.updateControls(this.formGroup);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Recursively update all form controls, since we are going to display error messages
   */
  private updateControls(formGroup: FormGroup): void {
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
      const control = formGroup.get(field);

      if (control instanceof FormControl) {
        control.markAsTouched({onlySelf: true}); // Otherwise validation color is not shown
        control.updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true})
      } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
        this.updateControls(control);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Do note the formgroup that is injected, we can set it on the new form in this component so that the form controls are correctly transcluded (otherwise Angular does not recognize the form controls). *This is the problem that stopped me from using template driven forms*

When the form is submitted we now check if it is valid. If it isn't then we recursively loop trough all the FormControls (`updateControls()`) and update the status to 'touched' (since we are going to set errors on them we can also mark them 'touched'). In order to make Angular send out an `stateChange` event to it's listeners we need to use `updateValueAndValidity()`. And since we are already looping trough every formControl we can set the `onlySelf` flag to `true`.

*The template that belongs to the form:*

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()"
      [formGroup]="form"
      class="no-validate">

  <ng-content></ng-content>

</form>
```

By making sure Angular emits and event when the form is invalid we've created a hook that can be used for custom messages (remember `ng-messages` from Angular 1.x?). More information on that can be found [here][2].

If you want to use this in a template this would look as follows:

```
<val-message-form (onSubmit)="login()" [formGroup]="form">
  <fieldset>
    <!-- Username -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email"
             formControlName="username">
    </div>

    <!-- Password -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password"
             formControlName="password">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success shadow-none">
      {{'LOGIN_PAGE.LOGIN.SHORT' | translate}}
    </button>
  </fieldset>
</val-message-form>
```

Note the `[formGroup]` tag, Angular uses the same tag to define a reactive form on a form. Removing the tag from the input results in an angular error telling you that it needs the tag in order to assign the `formControlName`. We can make sure a programmer doesn't run into this problem by using the same tag for injecting the form into the directive. Angular will be happy and you can get the form inside the directive, win-win situation!